# Create dynamic Rectangle collection in html using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Hello All I am a beginner in html and js, and I am trying to create a webpage containing a rectangle collection in which when a new rectangle is created is placed beside the previous rectangle.
I have created a `div` element and trying to add newly created `div` (rectangle shape with background color different based on condition), but I am not able to get the desired result.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>parkIn</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <style>
    .ParkSlots {
        border: solid 1px;
        width: 60%;
        height: 400px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        position: fixed;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        display: inline;
    }

    .row:before,
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .col-1 {
        width: 15%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        height: 350px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    </style>

    <body onload="viewCreate()">
        <div class="ParkSlots">
            <div class="row" id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script language="javascript">
    function viewCreate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                createGreenBox();
            } else {
                createRedBox();
            }
        }
    }

    function createRedBox() {
        var = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'col-1';
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
    }

    function createGreenBox() {
        var = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'col-1';
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

I want an output that looks something like this:

[image: example]

Comment: Can you tell us what you're currently seeing, including any console errors?

Comment: First try replacing `for(int i=0;i<5;i++)` with `for(var i=0;i<5;i++)` `int` is not used in that way in js. Also give your variable divs you create the name 'div'.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..it helped me a lot guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in glancing at your code, I see at least two typos:

- `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {` - in JS, `int` is not used in this way. Use `var i = 0...`
- `var = document.createElement('div');` - you're missing a variable name on this line in both create box functions. I assume, from the rest of the code you need `var div = document.createElement('div');`

The rest will be CSS. In your stylesheet you're applying the border to the outter most containing div, from you're example, you need to apply that to the `.col-1` class. You'll also want to use `display:inline-block` on that class, and set widths and margins to play nicely with the border size. I took the liberty of creating a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzdtfk0o/) for you with my recommended changes.

Comment: i have one more issue,can you please help me,how do i had onClick="function Name" to each rectangle.

Comment: When you're creating the divs, add a call to `div.addEventListener('click', functionName)`.